# Wordpress Development: Why am I seeing duplicate urls when I use "wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()" to get the featured image?

Tags: url, duplicates, http-status-code-404, repeat

I'm developing a theme on a local development server. But when I try to get the featured image of posts into my home page, I get a 404 error due to the url appearing like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/crystal/%E2%80%9Dhttp:/localhost:8888/crystal/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/04/restaurant-kitchen-inspired-design-ideas.png
```

See how the domain repeats itself?

I've checked my wp_options table in the database and it looks correct. Both "siteurl" and "home" does have the "http://" already and does not have a "/" after the url. I also already tried adding this script to my wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8888/crystal');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8888/crystal');
```

and this to my functions.php file:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://localhost:8888/crystal' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://localhost:8888/crystal' );
```

but that didn't fix it.

So far, it seems to be only happening when I try to use "wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()" to get the featured image.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'tournament',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => '10'
   );
$tournaments_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $tournaments_loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $tournaments_loop->have_posts() ) : $tournaments_loop 
    >the_post();
      // Set variables
      $title = get_the_title();
      $description = get_the_content();
      $tournament_date_time = get_field('tournament_date_time');
      $location = get_field('location');
      $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
       get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
      $tournament_image = $featured_image[0];
      // Output
      ?>
      <div class=”tournament”>
        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $tournament_date_time; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $location; ?></p>
        <img src=”<?php echo $tournament_image;  ?>” alt=”<?php echo 
        $title; ?>”>
      </div>
      <?php
       endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
   endif; ?>
```

Thank you.